# How to use scapy "sendpfast" on windows?

Tags: python, windows, scapy

**ENV:windows 7 python 2.6.6**
`E:\>pip list
DEPRECATION: Python 2.6 is no longer supported by the Python core team, please
dnet (1.12)
gnuplot-py (1.8)
numpy (1.3.0)
pcap (1.1-scapy-20090720)
pcapy (0.10.10)
pip (8.0.2)
pycrypto (2.1.0)
pyreadline (1.5)
PyX (0.12.1)
scapy (2.2.0)
setuptools (21.2.1)
You are using pip version 8.0.2, however version 8.1.2 is available.`

I want to simulate syn flood and icmp flood,Just only specify 1500-2000 packets per second

`>>> sendpfast(icmp,pps=2000)
ERROR: while trying to exec [tcpreplay]: [Error 2]`

It seems to that I must install the `tcpreplay`,but the `tcpreplay` used on Linux/OS X,
Is there some method like `sendpfast` called on windows?

Comment: I found tcpreplay compilation for win32 and installed but still work to get things running. I added path to tcpreplay to windows PATH variable and can call tcpreplay32 from terminal, but still receiving "error OSError: Could not execute sendpfast(), is it installed ?"

Comment: Adam Mierzwiak Have you tried to add the path of tcpdump using: `from scapy.config import conf`
and then `conf.prog.tcpreplay = "/path/to/tcpdump"` ?